# Wordpress on IIS cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: wordpress, curl, iis, plugins

I've installed WordPress on IIS on my local dev computer. Everything works fine apart from when I'm trying to install a plugin. That's when I get the "Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" and the installation fails.

I've tried some of the suggestions in related questions like downloading the certificate and making sure the curl.cainfo is pointing at the right place but at the end the "solution" was to turn off my proxy.

So the question is (as the problem seems to be that I'm using a proxy) if there is a way to specify proxy details for curl. Is this done in the php.ini file (I couldn't see any proxy related settings there)? Does curl have somewhere a settings file ?

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:

1- download this [certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and move to a directory and copy It's Address. Example: "C:\cacert.pem"

2- go to your php directory and edit php.ini (iis default php location is "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\PHP\v7.4")

3- find line that contains curl.cainfo , uncomment it and point it to downloaded certificate address:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\cacert.pem"
```

4- save the file

5- open terminal and enter following code to reset iis

```
iisreset
```